# python3 decode str to utf8

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode, mojibake

I have a str variable in Python 3.6, which is as following:

```
\xc3\xa4\xc2\xb8\xc2\xad\xc3\xa5\xc2\x9b\xc2\xbd\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb0\xc2\x91\xc3\xa7\xc2\x94\xc2\x9f\xc3\xa9\xc2\x93\xc2\xb6\xc3\xa8\xc2\xa1\xc2\x8c
```

I want to decode the str to  chinese, I first encode the str and then decode it, but it can't work, my code is as following:

```
str = '\xE4\xB8\xAD\xE5\x9B\xBD\xE6\xB0\x91\xE7\x94\x9F\xE9\x93\xB6\xE8\xA1\x8C'
str.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

the output is as following:

```
Ã¤Â¸Â\xadÃ¥Â\x9bÂ½Ã¦Â°Â\x91Ã§Â\x94Â\x9fÃ©Â\x93Â¶Ã¨Â¡Â\x8c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like latin-1 [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), UTF-8 encoded text which was incorrectly decoded as latin-1.

```
>>> s = '\xE4\xB8\xAD\xE5\x9B\xBD\xE6\xB0\x91\xE7\x94\x9F\xE9\x93\xB6\xE8\xA1\x8C'
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'中国民生银行'
```

I can't understand Chinese, but Google translate thinks that says "China Minsheng Bank". Does the output make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bytes` for 8 bit string data, not ordinary string. Notice the `b` in front of the string:

```py
>>> b'\xE4\xB8\xAD\xE5\x9B\xBD\xE6\xB0\x91\xE7\x94\x9F\xE9\x93\xB6\xE8\xA1\x8C'.decode()
'中国民生银行'
```

Your first `str` is incorrectly decoded *double UTF-8*, and you can fix it by:

```py
>>> s = '\xc3\xa4\xc2\xb8\xc2\xad\xc3\xa5\xc2\x9b\xc2\xbd\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb0\xc2\x91\xc3\xa7\xc2\x94\xc2\x9f\xc3\xa9\xc2\x93\xc2\xb6\xc3\xa8\xc2\xa1\xc2\x8c'
>>> s.encode("ISO-8859-1").decode().encode("ISO-8859-1").decode()
'中国民生银行'
```

Comment: Why ISO-8859-1 (latin-1), you might ask: the first 256 Unicode characters map directly to bytes in that charset, and since it also used to be the *default* charset in most Western systems, most flawed Unicode conversions are based on it. Each `.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode()` cycle undoes one extra ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion. In a sense, you could say that the string variable is *triple UTF-8* because getting rid of two makes it right.

Comment: how can I translate the plain str to b'......', I used the encode first  as my code ,but it can't work